# Shell script error : line 170: [: missing ']'

Tags: bash, shell

i have the error named in the tittle in shell scripts when i execute this:

```
    if [ $[ $op1 % $op2 ] == 0 ] and [ $res -ne 0 ]
    then
        resp
    else
        divi
    fi
```

thanks.

Comment: `$[` is not bash syntax. The syntax for an arithmetic expression is `$(( ... ))`

Comment: @Barmar [It actually is, but it's deprecated.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209833/117037)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I get `./test.sh: line 3: %  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%  ")`. I'm using Bash 5.0. Please make a [mre]. To start, do `$op1` and the other variables need to be defined? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You can [edit].

Comment: `and`???  What do you expect the "and" to do?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, but you probably want something like: `if [ $((op1 % op2)) -eq 0 ] && [ $res -ne 0 ]; then resp; else divi; fi`

Comment: Check that that line does not have DOS line-ending (`\r\n` instead of `\n`). You could use `dos2unix` to fix.

Comment: Next time, add the output of `$ bash --version`

Answer (score -1):

Your first line violates several shell syntax rules.

```
if [ $[ $op1 % $op2 ] == 0 ] and [ $res -ne 0 ]
```

`and` has no meaning in a shell. Just like in C the correct syntax is `&&`.

And math expressions use `$(( ... ))`.

So you probably meant:

```
if [ $(( $op1 % $op2 )) == 0 ] && [ "$res" -ne 0 ]
```

I also added quoting to `$res` as otherwise expansion takes place. E.g. if `$res` equals `*`, it would not compare `*` to zero but it would expand *, replacing it with the first filename in the current directory and this could cause the test to be true despite `$res` being `*`. To prevent this, you must quote `$res`. You don't need quoting for `$op1` and `$op2` as in math expression no shell expansion is performed.

Comment: There are no syntax violations. It simply calls `[` with a number of arguments, one of which is the word `and`. `$[...]` is a deprecated form of arithmetic expansion (so old that neither the syntax nor even its deprecation are documented anymore).

Comment: `[`, on the other hand, will complain about receiving too many arguments.

Comment: @chepner `and` is a syntax violation. If the syntax is valid, the shell would not throw a parse error. A parse error always means invalid syntax! Also ShellCheck clearly says it is a syntax violation. https://www.shellcheck.net/